# Using tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode to generate QR codes

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-14.04, qr-code

I have installed the `tc-lib-barcode` library on **Win10** localhost (using composer) and on a remote operational server to generate QR codes. It works great on the **Win10** localhost, but not on the remote server. 
The problem is that on the remote server the code line "`$imageData = $bobj->getPngData();`" causes it to freeze. I am guessing that the problem is something to do with the installation (removed and re-installed several times) or with PHP extensions and I stuck for a test that will point to the actual problem. Any comments or tips would be appreciated.
Here is the essential code I am using:

````
require ('../../vendor/autoload.php');
$barcode = new \Com\Tecnick\Barcode\Barcode();
$bobj = $barcode->getBarcodeObj('QRCODE,H', 'EditInvolvement.php?toID='.$InvolvementID, - 16, - 16, 'black', array(- 2, - 2, - 2, - 2))->setBackgroundColor('#f0f0f0');
$imageData = $bobj->getPngData();
file_put_contents('qr-code/'.$InvolvementID.'.png', $imageData); ```
````

Comment: I re-booted the server and it is working. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time ...

Comment: Good to hear you could solve this. As restarting the server is probably not helpful to others in the future when they encounter a similar issue, I vote to close this question.

Comment: Yes - close is good. The learning point was that when you apply a load of updates and extensions to an Ubuntu server and you don't bother to reboot or restart, it might not co-operate. That learning is inappropriate here! Thanks for looking dbrumann.